# Return custom UITableViewCell to non-editing state

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdk

I've subclassed a UITableViewCell to create custom layout and animations for my table view. Basically, when I swipe left, I enter edit mode and when I swipe right, I exit edit mode -- each with the appropriate animation.

The swiping is working as expected, but I can't seem to figure out how to set a cell to a non-editing state whenever the table view scrolls or another cell enter the editing state.

The idea is to reset the cell to the "normal" state whenever the tableview scrolls or the users starts editing (swipes left) on another cell.

Here's my custom UITableViewCell class:

```
//
//  CustomTableViewCell.m
//
//  Created by Spencer Müller Diniz on 27/03/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Family. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

@synthesize customView;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        CGRect customFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, self.contentView.bounds.size.height);

        self.customView = [[CustomTableViewCellView alloc] initWithFrame:customFrame];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.customView];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer* sgrLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwipedLeft:)];
        [sgrLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:sgrLeft];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer* sgrRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwipedRight:)];
        [sgrRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:sgrRight];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)cellSwipedLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (!self.isEditing)
        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)cellSwipedRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (self.isEditing)
        [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    if (self.isEditing) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            self.customView.forgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(-100.0f, 0.0f, self.customView.forgroundView.frame.size.width, self.customView.forgroundView.frame.size.height);
        }];

    }
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            self.customView.forgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.customView.forgroundView.frame.size.width, self.customView.forgroundView.frame.size.height);
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. So the delegate, scrollViewDidScroll will be called when you begin to scroll the table. So inside the delegate, you can make the necessary changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried calling [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES] inside scrollViewDidScroll hoping that that would set every cell that's being edit to a normal state, but it didn't work.

Comment: is the delegate getting called?

Comment: Do you want different behavior for each cell ?

Comment: @Anil, yes, it's being called (confirmed with NSLog).

Comment: @iphonic9, no, all cells should present the same behavior. I've been reading about this, and it seems that the way to go is to subclass UITableView and control some cell behavior from there.